# Check if a value exists in multiple tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of last names and their unique id's. In our database, we have two tables relating to last names. the first table has current last name, and the second table has alias/past last names. How do I return only the last name and id of individuals where the last name does not exist in both tables?

I've tried using `NOT IN:`

```
SELECT 
    A.[ID], A.[Last Name]
FROM 
    Involvement_Data A
INNER JOIN 
    DIM_CONSTITUENT B ON A.[ID] = B.[LOOKUPID]
LEFT JOIN 
    DIM_CONSTITUENTALIAS C ON B.[CONSTITUENTSYSTEMID] = C.[CONSTITUENTSYSTEMID]
WHERE 
    A.[Last Name] NOT IN (B.[LASTNAME], C.[LASTNAME]);
```

But the tables seem to get evaluated individually, causing me to get values back because it didn't exist in `DIM_CONSTITUENT` OR `DIM_CONSTITUENTALIAS`. It doesn't evaluate the tables together as a whole. I've also tried using `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery, but seem to still get results I'm not looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your're almost there

```
SELECT  A.[ID],
        A.[Last Name]
FROM    Involvement_Data A
LEFT JOIN
        DIM_CONSTITUENT B
ON      A.[ID] = B.[LOOKUPID]
LEFT JOIN
        DIM_CONSTITUENTALIAS C
ON      A.[ID] = C.[CONSTITUENTSYSTEMID]
WHERE   B.[LASTNAME] is null or C.[LASTNAME] is null;
```

**Edit**

As @Cameron correctly pointed out, this answer was lacking any explaination, so here it is.

What you need to do is preserve all the rows from your first table and match them with the rows of the other two, when possible. The resulting set will be something like

```
tableA   | tableB   | tableC
somerow1 | somerow1 | somerow1
somerow2 | NULL     | somerow2
somerow3 | somerow3 | NULL
somerow4 | NULL     | NULL
```

The rows you want to keep are those whose name are not in both tableB and tableC, so you can just filter for one of the two being null

Comment: Almost a code only answer. You might want to explain replacing the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`, and the use of `IS NULL`.